# Testing protocol extension with default implementations

Tags: ios, swift

In past projects, I've had an object use constructor injection for the objects it needs to get some other information.  For example:

```
class Foo {
   let appInfo: AppInfoType 

   init(appInfo: AppInfoType) {
       self.appInfo = appInfo
   } 
}

protocol AppInfoType {
    func build(bundle: Bundle) -> String?
}
```

And then if within Foo, information about the app like build is needed, it can use AppInfoType to get that info.  I thought I would see what this looked like with protocol extensions.

```
extension AppInfoType {
    func build(bundle: Bundle) -> String? {
        return bundle.infoDictionary?[kCFBundleVersionKey as String] as? String
    }
}

class Foo: AppInfoType {

}
```

So now I can achieve the same thing within Foo by just calling `build(bundle: Bundle.main)`.   But is there any easy way to test this now?  With the first way, I could still create a MockAppInfoType and provide an implementation for build(bundle: Bundle), but now I don't really see a way to do this unless the protocol extension maybe depended on another protocol where I could inject a mock for that protocol.

Comment: Interesting question. Have you checked this out yet? https://www.marcopace.it/swift-testing-protocol-extension-default-implementation/

Comment: @aunnnn Ya they introduce another protocol within the extension itself from briefly looking at it which I could do. I was just curious if there were other practices without introducing another additional protocol.